# Recover Container in Proxmox

Tags: ubuntu, server, containers, virtualization, proxmox

I am using Proxmox for all of my Container and Virtual Machines.  Recently, I updated my Nextcloud Container from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using the command line `do-release-upgrade`.

The container upgraded to 20.04 and rebooted... but, it never came back online afterwards. When I try to start it from the Proxmox console using `pct start 107`

> Job for pve-container@107.service failed because the control process
> exited with error code.
>
> See "systemctl status
> pve-container@107.service" and "journalctl-xe" for details. command
> 'systemctl start pve-container@107' failed: exit code 1

Both "systemctl" and "journalctl" just state that the service failed to start.

Thus, my question... how do I recover the files from that Container?  I can make a new Nextcloud server (and remember to take snapshots)... but, how do I recover the files?

Answer (score 0):

NEVERMIND, I fixed it!

https://gist.github.com/ammgws/6c959cf60ba3fb3d6f91698efb7be3a9

You have to modify the list of known distros!

```
#Edit /usr/share/perl5/PVE/LXC/Setup/Ubuntu.pm and add 18.04 to list of known distros.
    
    my $known_versions = {
        '18.04' => 1, # bionic
        '17.10' => 1, # artful
        '17.04' => 1, # zesty
        '16.10' => 1, # yakkety
        '16.04' => 1, # xenial
        '15.10' => 1, # wily
        '15.04' => 1, # vivid
        '14.04' => 1, # trusty LTS
        '12.04' => 1, # precise LTS
    };
```